# What is the recommended mechanism used in UWP for headless IPC implementations?

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-services, ipc, background-task

If there wasn't a requirement for UWP app specifically, I would have gone for implementing WCF endpoints hosted in Windows Service and set it to start when system starts-up. What is the analogous mechanism in UWP? Is it Background task or App Service or any other? So basically, the requirement is to have an IPC across remote machines available right when the OS starts-up.

Comment: Host it in a service and use some form of IPC to connect a uwp to the service on the machine. Like wcf. Which would be convenient, I suppose.

Comment: With service, I believe you are referring to Windows Service. Do all UWP platforms supports Windows Services?

Comment: Your question could use an [edit] where you outline your exact requirements.